# Don't know why the error is always there, inner join issue?

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT bookingid, customer.customerid, flightid, numseats, firstname, surname, billingadress, email
FROM flightbooking, leadcustoemr;
INNER JOIN customerid ON flighbooking.customerid = leadcustomer.customerid;
```

I get a syntax error at or near "SELECT" when i run it in PG Admin 4, where is the problem, i think it is in the inner join, but unsure.

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Remove the semi-colon after the from clause. It goes at the very end (only).

Comment: There is a spelling error in leadcustoemr, please fix that @Holly-Tucker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a semicolon after leadcustomer (which seems to have a typo itself) - that ends your select statement and the inner join isn't included (in addition, the inner join isn't using the correct table names).  Also in the select you are using a column from the customer table (and that table is not joined at all).

I think you are trying to join the flightbooking and leadcustomer tables with the Inner Join and not actually trying to add in a third table.  I edited your query here:

```
SELECT bookingid, flightbooking.customerid, flightid, numseats,
   firstname, surname, billingadress, email
FROM flightbooking
INNER JOIN leadcustomer ON (flightbooking.customerid = leadcustomer.customerid);
```

Comment: Yes, i need to join them because both contain customerid

Comment: OK, so the FROM above joins them properly.  Your SELECT still contains customer.customerid and you have not included the customer table.  That's the case of the error.

Comment: Add your table definitions to the question  - also check that you don't have any other text any your query window that you may accidentally be running along with the query.

Comment: If the code is copy & paste you also have misspelled the flightbooking table name (missing a 't').

Comment: And perhaps leadcustomer too !?

Comment: Thanks @SteveLovell - fixed the flightbooking table in the join.  I went with my guess as to the correct spelling on leadcustomer as the OP spelled it two ways in the question.

Comment: Sorry, is there any way i can get it working without a inner join?

Comment: You can do `FROM flightbooking, leadcustomer WHERE flightbooking.customerid = leadcustomer.customerid`  but that is just another way to write an inner join.  If you need both tables, you have to join them.  That's how SQL works.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for join has two forms according to this: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-join.html

```
SELECT *
FROM A, B
WHERE A.id = B.id;
```

So rewriting the query according to above syntax:

```
 SELECT bookingid, customer.customerid, flightid, numseats, firstname, 
 surname, billingadress, email
 FROM flightbooking, leadcustomer
 WHERE flightbooking.customerid= leadcustomer.customerid
```

more standard syntax is:

```
SELECT *
FROM A
INNER JOIN B
ON A.id = B.id
```

So rewriting the query results in:

```
SELECT bookingid, customer.customerid, flightid, numseats, firstname, surname, 
billingadress, email
FROM flightbooking
INNER JOIN  leadcustomer 
ON flighbooking.customerid = leadcustomer.customerid;`
```

and you could use aliases to make it shorter:

```
SELECT bookingid, customer.customerid, flightid, numseats, firstname, surname, 
billingadress, email
FROM flightbooking fb
INNER JOIN  leadcustomer  lc
ON fb.customerid = lc.customerid;
```

Comment: @Holy Tucker, Please Accept the answer if it worked.